# Azure Function returning empty data set from Cosmos Db Mongo Collection

Tags: .net, mongodb, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I have an Azure function that is querying a cosmos db mongo collection that is certainly holding data.

[image: Data is in the collection]

However, when querying through my azure function, the function is returning an empty array.

My function looks something like:

```
    [FunctionName("GetAll")]
    public static IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = null)]HttpRequest req, 
        TraceWriter log, [Inject(typeof(IWarehouseStateRepository))]IWarehouseStateRepository repoW)
    {
        log.Info("GetAll Function is processing a request");
        var warehouses = repoW.GetAllWarehouses();
        return warehouses != null ? 
            (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult(warehouses) :
            new BadRequestObjectResult("Something went wrong with this request");
    }
```

I am injecting a custom type for my warehouse repository which depends on a db configuration context which looks something like this:

```
public class StateContext : IStateContext
{
    private readonly IMongoDatabase _database = null;
    private readonly string _connectionString;
    private readonly string _dbName;
    private readonly string _collectionName;

    public StateContext()
    {

        _connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AggregateDbConnectionDev");
        _dbName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AggregateDbNameDev");
        _collectionName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AggregateDbCollectionDev");

        MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.FromUrl(new MongoUrl(_connectionString));
        settings.SslSettings = new SslSettings() { EnabledSslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 };

        var client = new MongoClient(settings);
        if (client != null)
            _database = client.GetDatabase(_dbName);
    }

    public IMongoCollection<WarehouseState> WarehouseState
    {
        get
        {
            return _database.GetCollection<WarehouseState>(_collectionName);
        }
    }
}
```

The function throws no errors or exceptions.

And the repo query:

```
    public IEnumerable<WarehouseState> GetAllWarehouses()
    {
        var warehouses = _context.WarehouseState.Find(_ => true).ToList();
        return warehouses;
    }
```

Does anyone have any ideas what could be going wrong here? Do I need to set up cosmos Db connection in a different way with azure function?

This setup has worked previously before moving the logic over to an azure function.

Comment: Try to log in the function code:
log.Info(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AggregateDbConnectionDev"));
log.Info(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AggregateDbNameDev"));
log.Info(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AggregateDbCollectionDev"));

do you see correct values?

Comment: Yeah, doing this presents the correct values that I have defined in my local settings.

Comment: Did you try creating the client in the functions body to see if the Inject is not causing any issues?

Comment: I haven’t tried that as I would like to keep that logic separated from the function. I will try this and see if it changes anything, but the mongo db is surely getting queried as is, because I can see the requests coming in through azure portal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I inserted into the collection using the same code I have above, and it inserted into a new collection in the database with the same collection name.. still not sure why, but I guess it is working now.